# Will Wubi work on a Truecrypt Full Disk Encryption Windows partition?

Tags: windows, wubi, truecrypt

I have a windows machine using Truecrypt 7.1a FDE. I would like to use wubi to install Ubuntu within windows. Will doing this cause any issues with my system booting up? From what I understand Wubi does not modify any bootloaders. All it does is modify some boot settings within windows. So in theory the Truecrypt custom bootloader will remain the same, and after I get through the truecrypt prompt, have the option of windows or Ubuntu right?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 2):

#### Sorry, not possible with Full Disk Encryption

It will not cause any issues...until after you select the "Wubi" entry on the boot menu. Wubi will not boot, complaining about a missing root.disk.

This happens because Wubi-Ubuntu does not have the Truecrypt driver necessary to access the underlying encrypted NTFS disk (which contains its `root.disk`).

Answer (score 0):

I am using a fully encrypted windows and as usual wubi lives inside the windows disk. and it boots up without problem.